# How to update google map v2 location from background service android

Tags: android, service, maps, location

I have a background service that implements LocationListener and will provide Location updates periodically. I want to then use those location updates to update the user position on a map in the main activity. I'm able to pass the latitude longitude data via an intent to the main activity, but I don't know how to use that data to display the user's location.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Specifically these lines

```
LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));
```